# Create playable preview of video file

Tags: java, android, video

I have a file `movie.mp4` that I wish to create a preview of and play in a `VideoView`. For the purpose of this question let's say `movie.mp4` is 30 megabytes.

I want to extract the first 10 megabytes of video from `movie.mp4` and save it in a temporary file. I will feed this file into the `VideoView` and play it.

This is what I've done so far:

```
// Get movie file.
File f = getMovieFile("movie.mp4");

// Create temporary file.
File t = File.createTempFile("preview", "mp4");
t.deleteOnExit();

// Create input stream.
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 2048);

// Create output stream to temp file.
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(t));

byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
int totalRead = 0;
int bytesRead;

int maxBytes = (int) Math.pow(2, 20) * 10; // 10 megabytes

// Write data from input to output.
while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1 && totalRead < maxBytes) {
    bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    bos.flush();
    totalRead += bytesRead;
}

bos.close();

// Play the preview.
mVideoView.setVideoPath(t.getAbsolutePath());
mVideoView.start();
```

When I run this bit of code Android complains and tells me that the file is unplayable. If I remove the 10 megabyte restriction and let the loop run its course, the `VideoView` will play the file just fine.

I'm guessing that when the preview is created and only data from one part of the file is copied, some important meta-data from the original `mp4` file is missing in the new one. This is just a guess though.

Comment: Your guess sounds good. Why not check the MP4 file in a hex editor on your PC or via online? If you don't see the word **moov** in first few bytes (without any scrolling down) then your metadata is at the end. You'll need a tool to move the **moov** (bad pun not intended), You could try manually copying the metadata from end of 30mb file and placing it at end of 10 mb file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be in your video,
a partial mp4 must have metadata at the beginning of the file.

While there are tons of articles about encoding MPEG 4 videos with FFmpeg, most of them fail to warn you about something: most video players will not start the playback until the metadata is available (meaning if that data is placed at the back-end of file, as done by some encoders, the whole video must be downloaded first to reach the metadata & playback begins).

This example use ffmpeg for create a mp4 faststart video:

> ffmpeg.exe -i INPUT_FILE_NAME_HERE -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline
>   -preset slow -b:v 800k -c:a libvo_aacenc **-movflags faststart** OUTPUT_FILE_NAME.mp4